# Trucrypt volume on Raid5

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt, raid-5, array

I have a NAS with the system disk on SSD and 8 HDD's in a RAID5 configuration (using an IBM5015 card).  The RAID5 volume is encrypted using truecrypt.

What happens if the computer dies ? My raid card has a battery and can shut itself down if it looses connection to the computer.

The part I'm unsure of is what is the impact of having an open truecrypt volume (in Win7). Will I still be able to access the data on the encrypted drive, or only the unencrypted partitions/arryay ?

Comment: Hi vcarter, welcome to Super User! Your question is a little difficult to follow/understand. Can you try to [edit] it for clarity? For more help, you can see [help], [ask], or ask in [chat]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Provided your RAID card does not die (or you have a spare), and provided your RAID array is in a readable state [ ie no more then 1 dead drive ] it is technically possible to recover data from a RAID array even if you need to transplant it to a different machine.

Truecrypt and RAID work on different layers, and should probably be considered as such - so break the problem down into 2 parts:

1. Can I move the RAID array to another system if I need to - The answer is typically yes,
   provided the hardware works.  As an aside most hardware experts will keep spare RAID 
   controllers as this can be a single point of failure (or use Software RAID which is
   generic).
2. Can I decrypt the Truecrypt volume - Provided you can read the RAID array data, and
   know the passphrase for the Truecrypt volume you can read this information.   That said,
   if you are just setting it up, you may want to reconsider Truecrypt as its status is
   "Unknown" (its suspected a 3 letter agency found and leaned on the author).

   The question as to whether the data will be "in tact" is largely a question of how
   its stored inside the Truecrypt container.   Most modern filesystems - including NTFS
   and EXT3/EXT4 have journals to protect against sudden failure, so you should be fine
   provided you are using one of these filing systems - and you most likely are.